# Sedona 1.4.1 with Spark 3.0, Scala 2.13 and jts-core dependency

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jts, apache-sedona

I am using Sedona 1.4.1 with pyspark (spark 3.0 and scala 2.13). When doing an ST_Intersects spark sql query which is giving the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.locationtech.jts.index.quadtree.IndexSerde tried to access method 'org.locationtech.jts.index.quadtree.Root org.locationtech.jts.index.quadtree.Quadtree.getRoot()' (org.locationtech.jts.index.quadtree.IndexSerde is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.spark.util.MutableURLClassLoader @6c1832aa; org.locationtech.jts.index.quadtree.Quadtree is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I've noticed that removing jts-core package solves this, however, due to other dependencies I cannot remove it permanently. I've also tried working with versions 1.18.0, 1.18.2 and 1.19.0 of jts-core.

Comment: Since you said, by removing jts-core package it solves the issues ; this implies that there are multiple versions of jts-core package. You can check this by printing the dependencyTree of your dependencies. One thing you can do is you can shade your version of jts-core by a shade-plugin. This way your version will be shaded (i.e. names changed) and be able to be used by other components.